# Fading in and out CSS stylesheet with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to implement more elegant elements in my site using `Javascript`.

---

> **Snippet**

```
<script>
    function nightmode(){
    var el = document.getElementById('myStyles'); // get stylesheet

    if ( el !== null ) {                // if it exists
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);  // remove it
    } else {                            // if not, add it
        var oLink = document.createElement("link") 

        oLink.id   = 'myStyles';
        oLink.href = "nightmode3.css";
        oLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
        oLink.type = "text/css"; 

        document.body.appendChild(oLink);
    }
}
</script>
```

---

That switches the site to nightmode. If you click the button, it switches nightmode on, or off. Simple enough.

However, I'd like a .5 second fadein/fadeout effect on each click, to make it less jarring. I've tried adding it via CSS, but that only works for fade in. How can I get both fade in and fade out effects?

Comment: Where are the transition definition rules located?  Are they only in nightmode or in each stylesheet?  Can you post some pertinent rules from each file?

Comment: Currently I use animate.css with:   animation-name: fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;

Comment: Why don't you add `style="...;"` inline on your HTML with `transition: all .5s;`? It's a little bit drastic but maybe it works!

Comment: Please edit your question to include pieces of your CSS files.

Comment: @FaustoNA Thats a reasonable idea- except I dont have access to my style declaration, I'm in a CMS situation!

Comment: hello RNPF. fyi: the "standard" way this type of thing is done is usually to apply a class to the relevant elements (or, if you're affecting the entire page, to the body) rather than hotswapping the CSS file out. then you would apply a css transition property to the elements that change, and apply the changes to the class. it's certainly possible to do it the way you're doing it, but it isn't the "standard" way of doing it.

Comment: the main reason for this is that it separates your view logic from your controller logic.

Comment: @RNPF You can try JavaScript: `element.style.transition='all .5s';` after having declared something like `var element = document.getElementById("yourElement");`

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Yeah- the logic is very wonky all over my stuff still- I'm not quite to the level where my stuff follows best practice strictly- I do need to get there, dont get me wrong, but at the moment am just trying to get stuff working.

Comment: @FaustoNA Trying that, it oddly enough simply cancels out the append entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few different ways to keep transitions working whenever you switch between styles.  The underlying thing to keep in mind is that you have to have a transition rule available for the transition to happen.  If you have it in one style but not the other, it will only happen whenever you change to the style that has it because otherwise there is no rule saying that there needs to be a transition.

---

## `<link>` Swapping Method

Basically, make sure that the transition rules are **always** available.  If they are in your night/day stylesheet but not other, then there is no longer a rule to transition.  That's why it would only work whenever you fade in.

Ideally though, you would probably want both sets of rules in a single file and then change between the active styles using a class on the `<body>` tag.  However, there are certainly use cases where you might want to still use two separate stylesheets that aren't both loaded simultaneously.  For example a high contrast stylesheet that might not be used by all users would waste memory.  However, I'd still probably use the class attribute on the `<body>` tag in case I ever wanted to combine them.

**index.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>CSS Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <p>I am text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <button id="day_mode">Day</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button id="night_mode">Night</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

**index.js**

```
/*jslint browser:true*/

(function () {
    "use strict";

    function addStylesheet(name, loc) {
        var sheet = document.createElement("link");
        sheet.id = name;
        sheet.href = loc;
        sheet.rel = "stylesheet";
        sheet.type = "text/css";

        document.head.appendChild(sheet);

        return sheet;
    }

    function removeStylesheet(sheet) {
        sheet.parentNode.removeChild(sheet);
        //document.getElementById(name).removeChild();
    }

    function go() {
        var dayButton = document.getElementById("day_mode"),
            nightButton = document.getElementById("night_mode"),
            daySheet,
            nightSheet;

        dayButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!daySheet) {
                if (nightSheet) {
                    removeStylesheet(nightSheet);
                    nightSheet = null;
                }
                daySheet = addStylesheet("day", "day.css");
            }
        });

        nightButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!nightSheet) {
                if (daySheet) {
                    removeStylesheet(daySheet);
                    daySheet = null;
                }
                nightSheet = addStylesheet("night", "night.css");
            }
        });
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", go);
}());
```

**base.css**

```
h1 {
    transition: color 1s;
}

p {
    transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
}
```

**day.css**

```
h1 {
    color: orange;
}

p {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
}
```

**night.css**

```
h1 {
    color: blue;
}

p {
    background-color: black;
    color: blue;
}
```

---

## `<body>` Class Namespacing

If you **do** want to try the `<body>` class method, here is a short implementation showing how to do that.

The basics of this is that you have a **namespace** for each version, day/night, of the CSS that you want to use and you prefix those mode rules with the relevant namespace.

Then, using JavaScript, you would remove or add the namespace class from your `<body>` tag using `document.body.classList.add()` and `document.body.classList.remove()`.

```js
/*jslint browser:true*/

(function() {
  "use strict";

  function go() {
    var dayButton = document.getElementById("day_mode"),
      nightButton = document.getElementById("night_mode");

    dayButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.body.classList.remove("night");
      document.body.classList.add("day");
    });

    nightButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.body.classList.remove("day");
      document.body.classList.add("night");
    });
  }
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", go);
}());
```

```css
h1 {
  transition: color 1s;
}
p {
  transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
}
body.day h1 {
  color: orange;
}
body.day p {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
body.night h1 {
  color: blue;
}
body.night p {
  background-color: black;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>CSS Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index2.css">
  <script src="index2.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="day">
  <main>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <p>I am text</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button id="day_mode">Day</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button id="night_mode">Night</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

---

## Alternate Stylesheet Relation

One other thing to note, is that if you use the `<link ... rel="stylesheet alternate" ...>` approach, the transitions will also still work.  I'm not sure what browsers still provide a means for users to switch their preferred rendering style manually.  Chrome does not provide a way, but FireFox does.  See the below screenshot.

[image: FireFox Page Style Menu]

Here is the markup I'm using for my `<head>` element.

```
<head>
    <title>CSS Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="day.css" title="Day">
    <link rel="stylesheet alternate" href="night.css" title="Night">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: @RNPF Good.  I also added a second example of how you could do this with a single stylesheet rather than adding and removing `<link>` tags.